# Recordtype is changing to null

Tags: opportunity, record-type, null

We're facing a pretty serious bug and have no idea what is causing it. Something is causing our opportunity record types to become null. They were a specific record type, and then through the day, something changes them to null:

[image]
[image]
[image]

We do have triggers that can affect opp record type, but on error, Master recordtype results. I actually have no idea how you could even set a recordtype to null. I've tried to do it with apex, soapforce, restforce, etc. It seems impossible to set a recordtype to null, so I have no idea how this can be happening.

We do have Heroku Connect which does have a two way connection. But Opportunities are streaming only to HC and not from.

If I could understand what could make an opportunity record type null, that may help us pinpoint where the change is coming from. There aren't any logs of the event - it is a total mystery!

Comment: The Master Record Type *is* null. Some systems export the Master Record Type may end up showing a value of 000000000000000AAA, but that's the "null" value (this value literally means 0 when converted to a number). If you're setting records to the Master Record Type, you're setting them to null. Does that help?

Comment: When we;ve tried to force it to be null, such as opportunity.recordtypeid = null or '', it then shows up as master - which is fine and great. We were never able to get it to show the above. What you see above, that isn't Master! We have controls in place that can handle master record types. But the above has caused several of our apps to crash because they are receiving a totally null value.

Comment: Perhaps you could enable Field History Tracking for the Record Type field, which would let you see when it's changed. It might help narrow things down. But again, the Master record type is also the null type. You can't normally set it unless your profile has no record types (but system mode code should allow it), which is why it's kind of challenging to get it to be null, but I think history tracking and/or debug logs might be able to help.